# django joins with many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, join

I've looked at multiple answers to similar questions on how to do a join over django models with a many to many relationship but none seem to work, could someone please help.

User -> your normal django user model

```
class Upload(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField(storage=FileSystemStorage(location='./xyz/xyz/'))
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class FollowerRelationship(models.Model):
   followed_content_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followed_fk')
   following_content_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='following_fk')
```

Now I'd like to select all Uploads from a given user's followers, how could I do that without hitting the storage system more than once?

Many thanks

Comment: It would be alot easier for us to give you an answer if you can post your models and related fields as they are, within a code snippet

Comment: @IşıkKaplan sure

Comment: You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) like `.prefetch_related("followed_fk", "following_fk")`

Comment: @SachinKukreja could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.objects.get(username='user')

follower = user.followerRelationship_set.all() 

Upload.objects.all().filter(owner__in=follower.values('following_content_creator'))
```

This should give all the Upload objects for a given user if the user follows the upload owner, hope it helps.

Comment: that didn't quite work, the program claims 'User' object has no attribute 'followerRelationship_set' which is not that surprising. 
I have working code:
followed = FollowerRelationship.objects.filter(following_content_creator__username='my_username').values("followed_content_creator")
    followed_uploads = Upload.objects.all().filter(owner__in=followed)

But I'm wondering if that makes two calls or just the one to the storage system, and if it makes two calls, how could I improve it

Comment: It's my bad it should rather be `followerrelationship_set`, you can access objects of the class that has a ForeignKey relationship to given class with `Has_A_ForeignKey_To_This.ojects.get().foreign_key_class_in_lower_chars_set.all()`

If you don't mind trying that it should be working now. 

Here are the docs for it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

And if you are trying to make it more efficient, learning SQL and writing getting it via raw SQL is faster.

Comment: it's still not working but I've checked out the docs and it does sound like your approach should work now...I suspect it might be because there's 2 fks of the same type (User) to the FollowerRelationship model. In any case, being able to execute raw sql queries is perfect, I can always resort to that. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried it out and indeed it didn't work but I came up with a, in my opinion, better approach to your database structure. I tested it to full proof so you can trust this one, :^)


Here is the imgur link for how it would all look(from bottom to top);


https://imgur.com/a/6etVt


Here is the link for slightly edited classes;


https://hastebin.com/itevadijum.py


Of course this is merely a suggestion but I think it would be easier to use this one. Anyway, I bothered you enough! Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No need to apologise! Sharing good knowledge is what this community is about :) I'll look into doing it your way today and most likely adopt it - thanks again